# Having trouble understanding proof of theorem concerning convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> Suppose that the function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. Then, the function $f$ is convex if and only if its' first derivative is an increasing function on the interval $(a,b)$.

So I've managed to prove the neccesary condition, which is that if a real function is convex and differentiable on the interval $(a,b)$ then its' first derivative is an increasing function, but I'm having trouble trying to prove the sufficient condition.

I've come across this proof over on ProofWiki:

[image: ProofWiki]

But I'm confused about the last part of the proof. How is $f$ convex by definition? How is $\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\leq \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}$ similar to the definition of a convex function?

Comment: Convex function characterized by the fact that points of any arc of its graph are under the corresponding  chord or on it.

Comment: @zkutch I am aware of that definition but I do not see how this inequality is related to it.

Comment: The inequality says: "the slope of a chord between points 1-2 is less than (or equal to) the slope of a chord between points 2-3". Which is equivalent to "(any) point 2 of the graph between points 1 and 3 is _below_ the 1-3 chord".

Comment: Using that the epigraph of a convex function is a convex set then consider the half-plane defined by the tangent line and that contains some the epigraph. Half-planes are convex, so their intersection will be a convex set. Now use the increasing derivative to show that the epigraph is a subset of all of these half planes, so when you take their intersection it leaves the epigraph which then must be convex.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks. It makes sense now.

Comment: The definition of "convex" is under the link which shows in blue on the page from which you took your screenshot from. If you explore the links in ProofWiki you should gain an understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote points $(x_i, f(x_i))$ on the function's graph with $P_i$, respectively, for $i\in\{1,2,3\}.$

Then the inequality  $$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\leq \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}$$ says: "the slope of a chord $P_1P_2$ is less than (or equal to) the slope of a chord $P_2P_3$".
Which results in "(any) point $P_2$ of the graph between points $P_1$ and $P_3$ is below (or at) the $P_1P_3$ chord".

Answer (score 0):

Let's take $f(q_1x_1+q_2x_2)\leqslant q_1f(x_1)+ q_2f(x_2)$. If we assume $x_1<x_2$, then $x=q_1x_1+q_2x_2$ is between $x_1, x_2$. On other hand any number between $x_1, x_2$ can be represent in given form by coefficients $q_1=\frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1}$ and $q_1=\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}$. So we have
$$f(x)\leqslant \frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1} f(x_1)+\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}f(x_2)$$
and, so
$$(x_2-x) f(x_1)+(x_1-x_2)f(x)+(x-x_1)f(x_2)\geqslant 0$$
I hope from here you can obtain the inequality of interest.